# How to update git repo or to create if there is no such repo

Tags: git, version-control, git-pull, git-clone

I want a script that will update the git repo. I want it to update the repo if the folder with the repo exists and I want to clone the repo if there is no such folder.

I want to specify 2 thing for that script:

- git remote url (for example `ssh://git.example.com/var/git/repo.git`)
- forder where the git repo should be (for example `/var/lib/git/repo`)

It is not very hard to write this kind of script, but I think that this task is something very common and it is already solved.

The task is pretty simple, but there are some things that should be done carefully. For example, the main branch of the repo can not the master, but something else, the scrip should give the non zero exit status in case of error, it should work if there is some changes in the repo, and so on.

So my question — what script can I use to carefully solve the task of cloning or updating the repo.

Answer (score 3):

Here is simple ruby code

```
REPO_PATH = '/Users/full_path/to_repo'
REPO_NAME = 'xxx'
GITHUB_URL = 'git@github.com:xxx/xxx.git'   

def change_dir_to_repo
  Dir.chdir(REPO_PATH)
  puts system('pwd')
end   

def git_repo_exists?
  if Dir.exists?(REPO_NAME)
    puts "Git repo #{REPO_NAME} exists."
    update_git_repo
  else
    puts "Git repo #{REPO_NAME} does not exists."
    clone_git_repo
  end
end   

def clone_git_repo
  system("git clone #{GITHUB_URL}")
  puts "Done"
end  

def update_git_repo
  puts "Changing directory to #{REPO_NAME}"
  Dir.chdir(REPO_NAME)
  puts "Changing branch to master"
  system('git checkout master')
  puts "updating git repo"
  system('git pull')
  puts "Done"
end  

change_dir_to_repo
git_repo_exists?
```

Comment: Sorry everything did not get printed as code. I will edit it once i will come back from break.

Comment: Thank you! But this script does not work correct when there is no master branch in the repo (I have several repos where the main branch is has other name than 'master')

Comment: @bessarabov Well, you can edit the script according to your needs. We can't write full script without knowing all of your requirements.

Comment: =) Well, I relly hoped that what I want is just a common thing and there is already a script for that.

Answer (score 1):

If I quickly had to do this, I would try node because it offers some good libraries for git integration and I think it's now a bit easier than bash if you're not used to any of them. The script would do the following:

1) Navigation to the folder and do a simple `git status`, any command would do, becauswe if it's not a git repo it will say so:

```
fatal: Not a git repository
```

1.a) If it's not a git repo a simple "git clone url" does the trick and the script exists

2.a) Ok, so it there is not an error, the git status will give you either a clean branch with no changes or it will tell you have changes

2.a.a) If you want to update now run a "git pull --ff-only" which will prevent unwanted merges. If this fails, then I think you should solve the problems manually.

2.a.b) If you have local changes I would exit the script as well.

Libraries to use:

I like [gift](https://github.com/sentientwaffle/gift) but there are many others if you look into npm. In case you don't want to follow my suggestion a bash script will do as well.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thank your for the answer, but I hoped to find the working script and not to implement this myself. By the way, just simple checking for git status is not enough — in the local repo there can be commits that are not in the remote repo — I think in this case the script should exit as well.

Comment: in that case the pull --ff-only would fail and the script would exit.

Answer (score 0):

Van also be run on a Build Server

```
#peventing failure  
mkdir $rep || true
#succeeds always
cd $rep
#one of them will do the job!
git clone $REMOTE_URL . || git pull
```

IF run on a Build Server, you Couleur appen git Status.